# Setting a functools.partial as an instance method in Python

Tags: python, class, methods, closures

I'm using `functools.partial` to create a closure, and using `setattr` to make is callable from a class instance. The idea here is to create a set of methods at runtime.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from functools import partial

class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    @classmethod
    def generateMethods(self):
        def dummy(conf1, self):
            print "conf1:", conf1
            print "self.val:", self.val
            print

        for s in ('dynamic_1', 'dynamic_2'):
            closed = partial(dummy, s)
            setattr(self, "test_{0}".format(s), closed)
```

It seems to me that `partial` would bind the current value of `s` to `dummy`'s first arg, which would free up `self` to be passed when this is called from an instance.

It's not working how I'd expect

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Dynamically create some methods
    MyClass.generateMethods()

    # Create an instance
    x = MyClass('FOO')

    # The dynamically created methods aren't callable from the instance :(
    #x.test_dynamic_1()
    # TypeError: dummy() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

    # .. but these work just fine
    MyClass.test_dynamic_1(x)
    MyClass.test_dynamic_2(x)
```

Is it possible to dynamically create methods which are closures, but callable from instances of the class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a Method to an Existing Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object)

Comment: @alfasin that question asks about adding methods to specific instances; my question asks about adding methods to a class, to be inherited by all instances

Comment: True, but the accepted answer shows how to do both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that when you're calling them using the instances they are actually not bound methods, i.e they have no knowledge about the instance. Bound methods insert the `self` to the arguments of the underlying function automatically when called, it is stored in the `__self__` attribute of bound method.

So, override [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) and see if the object being fetched is an instance of `partial` type or not, if yes, convert it to a bound method using [`types.MethodType`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.MethodType).

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from functools import partial
import types


class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    @classmethod
    def generateMethods(self):
        def dummy(conf1, self): 
            print "conf1:", conf1
            print "self.val:", self.val
            print

        for s in ('dynamic_1', 'dynamic_2'):
            closed = partial(dummy, s)
            setattr(self, "test_{0}".format(s), closed)

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        # Here we do have access to the much need instance(self)
        obj = object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        if isinstance(obj, partial):    
            return types.MethodType(obj, self, type(self))
        else:
            return obj


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyClass.generateMethods()

    x = MyClass('FOO')

    x.test_dynamic_1()
    x.test_dynamic_2()
```

Comment: This works! I guess there's no way of adding the closure as a `MethodType` right off the bat, rather than converting it on the fly when it's called?

Answer (score 10):

I think the new [`functools.partialmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod) is for this exact use case.

Straight from the docs:

```
>>> class Cell(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self._alive = False
...     @property
...     def alive(self):
...         return self._alive
...     def set_state(self, state):
...         self._alive = bool(state)
...     set_alive = partialmethod(set_state, True)
...     set_dead = partialmethod(set_state, False)
...
>>> c = Cell()
>>> c.alive
False
>>> c.set_alive()
>>> c.alive
True
```